# Panasonic fan not working

Tags: electrical

Panasonic fan works intermittently in conjunction with Lutron timer. It does not stay on or go through the timer sequence.

Comment: are you certain that Panasonic makes only one model of fan?

Comment: What the previous comment is trying to say is: you need to provide more specifics, including the exact model of the fan. Panasonic bathroom fans also may be configured with various control modules that plug into the fan chassis and affect the way the fan operates, so if you're asking about one of those, you need to provide specific information about any such modules that are installed, if any. Photos of the fan, with and without the cover installed, would help as well. All of the same thing applies to the Lutron timer as well. _Be specific_.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we could help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: What model are the fan and timer in question?

Comment: Likely the timer is solid state and not designed for use with a fan. Try a mechanical timer.